# Extract string between 2 delimiters

Tags: python, string, file, find

I'm trying to extract some words between two delimiters. It works for the files where the script find these delimiters, but for the others files, the code extract all of the file.

Example:

> File 00.txt:

```
'bqukfkb saved qshfqs illjQNqdj iohqsijqsd qsoiqsdqs'
```

> File 01.txt:

```
'jkhjkl dbdqs ihnzqid Bad value okkkk SPAN sfsdf didjsfsdf'
```

I want to open 2 or more files like these two and extract only words between: 
'Bad Value' and 'SPAN'.

My code works for the file 01.txt, but not for the 00.txt ( i think it's because it doesn't find the delimiters so he prints everything. How can i fix it ?

```
def get_path(): #return the path of the selected file(s)

    root = Tk()
    i= datetime.datetime.now()
    day = i.day
    month=i.month
    root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir = "Z:\SGI\SYNCBBG",title = "Select your files",filetypes = (("Fichier 1","f6365tscf.SCD*"+str(month)+str(day)+".1"),("all files",".*")))
    root.withdraw()
    return (root.filename)

def extraction_error(file): 
    f=open(file,'r')
    file=f.read()
    f.close()
    start = file.find('Bad value') +9
    end = file.find('SPAN', start)
    return(file[start:end])


paths=get_path()
cpt=len(paths)
for x in range(0,cpt):
 print(extraction_error(paths[x]))


Output : saved qshfqs illjQNqdj iohqsijqsd qsoiqsdq
         okkkk
```

So in this case i just want to extract 'okkkk' and not print ' saved....' for the other file.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your extraction_error function, you may want to test if the two key words can be found:

```
    start = file.find('Bad value') # remove + 9 here, put it later
    end = file.find('SPAN', start)
    if start != -1 and end != -1: # test if key words can be found, -1 for not found:
        return(file[start+9:end])
    else:
        return ""
```

Comment: Thanks Tianyun, it worked well. Now i saw that in some files i have the word that i want to extract appears several times. But with my function it just extract the first one it finds and exit. How can i fix it ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[string.find()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) return `-1` if the argument is not found in the string, example:

```
print "abcd".find("e")  # -1
```

You can just check the result before the return:

```
start = file.find('Bad value') + 9
end = file.find('SPAN', start)
if start == -1 or end == -1:
    return '' # Or None
return(file[start:end])
```

Comment: Is this an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out something, because you are adding 8 to the start variable. Find returns negative one if the string is not found. So what you end up doing is printing out the elements from [7:-1]. I would add an if statement before the print statement:

```
start = file.find('Bad value')
end = file.find('SPAN', start)
if start != -1 and end != -1:
    print(file[start + 9: end])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using re:

```
import re

def get_text(text):
    pattern= r'.+(Bad value)(.+)(SPAN).+'
    r=re.match(pattern,text)
    if r!=None and len(r.groups()) == 3:
        print(r.groups()[1])


lines = [
'jkhjkl dbdqs ihnzqid Bad value okkkk    SPAN sfsdf didjsfsdf'
,'ghghujh']

for line in lines:
     get_text(line)
```

Output:

```
okkkk
```